# Empty textbox bound with some decimal value

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox bound to some decimal value. Now, if I type something in it like 100 and clear it completely (empty). I save the data and it saves 1 in decimal value. Similarly if I tried 200 and clear textbox it saves 2. Remember decimal value is not null. Any ideas?

```
<TextBox 
    Height="23" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Text="{Binding Discount,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    MaxLength="50" 
    TabIndex="28" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    local:FocusExtension.IsFocused=
        "{Binding Path=IsDiscountFocused,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: can you please show your xaml code.

Comment: <TextBox Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Discount,Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="50" 
                          TabIndex="28"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding Path=IsDiscountFocused,Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

Comment: Discount is decimal property, and i am using MVVM

Comment: Are you clearing the TextBox by pressing backspace three times, i.e. to remove the three digits of 100? If so, and the FocusExtension is causing an update every time you change the text, then the last "legitimate" value you are left with is 1, after you removed the two zeroes. When you try to backspace the 1, a binding exception occurs because the value of the Discount can't be null. What do you want to happen when the user clears the TextBox?

Comment: I want 0 in the case of empty textbox. And yes, i am clearing by using backspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since String.Empty cannot be converted into a decimal per default. The last valid value is kept in the property.
You should use a converter as below.

Wpf

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ValueConverter x:Key="valueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource valueConverter}}" />
```

Converter:

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string && (string)value == "")
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Clr:

```
public decimal Value
{
    get { return (decimal)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Made my day for sure! :)

Answer (score 0):

i assume that your Discount property in your viewmodel looks like:

```
public decimal Discount {get;set;}
```

if you use backspace and clear your textbox you get a binding exception because "" can not convertet to decimal. so the last number remains in your property. actually this should happen when using UpdateSourceTrigger=Propertychanged. but nevertheless you can try using decimal?. if this not help you can also add a converter to convert the "" to a value your viewmodel can handle.

EDIT: i did not see you last comment. but in the case you want a 0 for an empty textbox, just use a converter to return 0 when "" is the input.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this converter. I mean best to fit in viewmodel. Thanks

Comment: What i get. you want me to do in Discount property set { if(value == string.empty) _discount = 0 else _discount = value}

Comment: see the answer from Eric he post a converter